# Laravel 5.3 Auth::login and Auth::loginUsingId undefined

Tags: laravel

I created a new table called ADMIN_USER with the field USERNAME and PASSWORD for authentication, but then when I tried to perform login, Hash::check return true as expected but the Auth::attempt return false.

Then I tried to remember the logged-in user before Hash::check or Auth::attempt, php reply with an error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\loginUsingId()

And the Auth:login under Hash::check does not remember anything.

Here is my authenticate method in the LoginController:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $user = new User();
    $user = $user->where('USERNAME' , $data['inputUsername'])->first();
    Log::info($user->PASSWORD);
    Log::info($data['inputPassword']);

    Auth:loginUsingId($user->id);

    /*
    if(Auth::attempt(array('USERNAME' => $data['inputUsername'], 'PASSWORD' => $data['inputPassword']))){
        return redirect($this->home); 
    }else{
        return redirect($this->index); 
    }
    */

    if(Hash::check($data['inputPassword'], $user->PASSWORD)){
         Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect($this->home); 
    }else{
        return redirect($this->index); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you migrated the migrations that come with Laravel already?  What tables does your database currently have?

Comment: The system is newly created, I manually created the ADMIN_USER table and added the $table property in the User class with the $fillable array changed to the according column name

Comment: Do I need to change the migration and execute some php command?

Comment: I believe the answer below should help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing PASSWORD to password and ID to id in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes pre-configured with a user and auth table that stores your session info, users, salted passwords, etc so no need to create your own table.  You can read more about this in the   [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication).

Laravel config won't know how to communicate with ADMIN_USERS unless you modify your authenticate class.

look in your application's database/migrations folder and you should find a timestamp_create_users_table.php file that contains a migration to create a users table with id, name, email, password, token, and timestamps.

If you don't see that then run:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Once you have that migration file in your migrations folder then just run.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Once this runs check your database and you should see a users table.  I'm pretty sure this will fix your Authentication issues.

I'd suggest you run through some of the free lessons available on laracasts.  It should help get you up to speed fairly quickly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solve the Auth::attempt return false problem by performing migration and changing the PASSWORD column to password, now the Auth::attempt returns true as expected but I cant retrieve the user data with Auth::user()

Comment: Did you add use Auth; to the controller you are trying to access the data through? Also are you logged in or accessing the page as a guest?  Run dd(Auth::check()); to check.